# Get data from JSON API and put into CSV in loop

Tags: java, json, loops, csv

I am managed to get the data out of an API and put into a CSV, but I have problems to put the data into the CSV in a loop because right now it always overwrites it in the CSV. And the next problem is that the date does not get shown in the CSV in different fields. In the CSV it looks

like this:

[image: CSV picture]

and I want all the data like in my console:

[image: console pic]

my code right now:

```
    JSONArray jsonarr_1 = (JSONArray) jobj.get("infectedByRegion");
            //Get data for Results array
            for(int i=0;i<jsonarr_1.size();i++)
            {
                //Store the JSON objects in an array
                //Get the index of the JSON object and print the values as per the index
                JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject)jsonarr_1.get(i);
                //Store the JSON object in JSON array as objects (For level 2 array element i.e Address Components)
                String str_data1 = (String) jsonobj_1.get("region");
                Long str_data2 = (Long) jsonobj_1.get("infectedCount");
                Long str_data3 = (Long) jsonobj_1.get("deceasedCount");

                System.out.println(str_data1);
                System.out.println("Infizierte: "+str_data2);
                System.out.println("Tote: "+str_data3);
                System.out.println("\n");

                   PrintWriter pw = null;
                    try {
                        pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:/Users/stelz/OneDrive/Desktop/Corona Daten/28.04.2020.csv"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String columnNamesList = "Bundesland,Infizierte,Tote";
                    // No need give the headers Like: id, Name on builder.append
                    builder.append(columnNamesList +"\n");
                    builder.append(str_data1+",");
                    builder.append(str_data2+",");
                    builder.append(str_data3);
                    builder.append('\n');
                    pw.write(builder.toString());
                    pw.close();
                    System.out.println("done!");









            }
            //Disconnect the HttpURLConnection stream
            conn.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV is probably a nice **comma** delimited file with UTF-8 encoding. The first line in the image from Excel is an evidence that **in the file** and **as text** the first line is correctly:

```
Thüringen,2170,80
```

But your Excel has probably national defaults for Western Europe, meaning semicolon (`';'`) as CSV separator, and CP1252 (slight variation of the Latin1 charset) for encoding.

How to fix?

Excel is known to have a very poor support for CSV file: read it as text (notepad or notepad++) or use LibreOffice calc which allows to declare the separator and the encoding when reading a CSV file.

If you have to stick to Excel, carefully build your file *for your own Excel*, use ISO-8859-1 charset and semicolons:

```
                ...
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                try {
                    pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:/Users/stelz/OneDrive/Desktop/Corona Daten/28.04.2020.csv"),
                                         "ISO-8859-1");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String columnNamesList = "Bundesland;Infizierte;Tote";
                // No need give the headers Like: id, Name on builder.append
                builder.append(columnNamesList +"\n");
                builder.append(str_data1+";");
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create many different CSVs? If this is not what you want and you want all the records in one CSV, then I recommend looping through the array, building a CSV with `StringBuilder` or some other CSV tool of which there are many, and then creating the file outside of your `for` loop.